# Declaring constructor for object that contains integer array

Tags: java, arrays, class, constructor, int

Here is how my constructor has been defined

```
    public One (int [] a, int [] b)
{
    A = a;
    B = b;
    C = new int [a.length + b.length];
}
```

This is how I am creating a object for this:

```
    One A = new One ([1,3,5], [1,5,3]);
```

I am getting multiple errors for this , like the constructor `(int,int,int,int,int,int)` is not defined and syntax error on tokens,delete these tokens.

Can someone please tell me where am i going wrong ? Thanks

Comment: sorry guys having some issues how to insert code here, i am editing it to proper format, thanks

Comment: You have you specify the type when creating an array (and create an instance); `new int[] {1, 3, 5}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not how you create an array in java. You need to use it like this: -

```
One A = new One (new int[] {1,3,5}, new int[] {1,5,3});
```

`new int[]` creates an integer array object.

`{1, 3, 5}` initializes the array inline.

---

As a side note, you should declare your variable starting with lowercase letter. In your code, your instance array reference should be `a` instead of `A`. And use `this.a` to access it to avoid name conflict between local and instance variable.

Comment: Gotta get just a little bit quicker... :)

Comment: @ppeterka.. haha :) Actually it took 1 and a half minutes to answer. ;)

Comment: I bet it took <=30 seconds to answer, and the other 1 minute polishing the answer to be real good. (I even needed to polish this comment a couple if times...)

Comment: @ppeterka. lol ;) Yeah of course. Polishing is more than required.

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR.. That you guessed right. ;) Actually I'm allowed to type only 1 comment per 15 seconds, so I'm a bit late on this. lol ;)

Answer (score 3):

your syntax for creating **anyonomous array** is wrong. you create an **anyonomous array** like this.

```
One A = new One (new int []{1,3,5}, new int[]{1,5,3});
```